# Markov chain mean return time to set of states

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stopping-times

I would like to solve the following problem, but I cannot find a good approach to it.

Let $X = (X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a homogeneous, irreducible and positive recurrent Markov chain with (countable) state space $S$ and stationary distribution $\pi$. For a subset $A\subseteq S$, let $(T_A^{(k)})_{k\geq 1}$ be the sequence of return times to $A$. Show that
$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{T_A^{(k)}}{k} = \frac{1}{\sum_{j\in A}\pi(j)}.$

I know that this holds for the case $A = \{i\}$ for any $i\in S$ and also read through the proof of it, but still don't see, how to generalise this to general subsets $A\subseteq S$.